# node.js to check out duplication value in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, duplicates

Now I'd like to save my json data into mongoose but the duplicate value had to be filtered.

```
my_json = [
  {"name":"michael","age":21,"sports":"basketball"},
  {"name":"nick","age":31,"sports":"golf"},
  {"name":"joan","age":41,"sports":"soccer"},
  {"name":"henry","age":51,"sports":"baseball"},
  {"name":"joe","age":61,"sports":"dance"},
];
```

Database data is :

```
{
   "name":"joan","age":41,"sports":"soccer"
}
```

Is there some specific method to avoid duplicate data insert to mongoose directly? It might be saved 4 of values except "joan" value.

Once I suppose to try to use "for statement", it was fine.
However I just want to make a simple code for that what could happen in a variety possible code.

```
for(var i = 0; i < my_json.length; i++){
    // to check out duplicate value
    db.json_model.count({"name":my_json[i].name}, function(err, cat){
        if(cat.length == 0){
           my_json_vo.savePost(function(err) {

           });
        }
    })
};
```

As you see I need to use count method whether the value is duplicated or not. I don't want to use count method but make it more simple..

Could you give me an advice for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can mark field as `unique` in [mongoose schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html):

```
var schema = new Schema({
   name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true}
   //...
});
```

Also, you can add [unique](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/) index for `name` field into your database:

```
db.js_model.createIndex( {"name": 1}, { unique: true, background: true } );
```

then, if new entity with the same name will be asked to save - mongo won't save it, and respond an error.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @Alex answer about adding unique key on the **name** field.

> You can use **insertMany()** method with **ordered** parameter set to
>   **false**. Like this...

```
let my_json = [
  {"name":"michael","age":21,"sports":"basketball"},
  {"name":"nick","age":31,"sports":"golf"},
  {"name":"joan","age":41,"sports":"soccer"},
  {"name":"henry","age":51,"sports":"baseball"},
  {"name":"joe","age":61,"sports":"dance"},
];
User.insertMany(my_json ,{ordered :false});
```

> This query will successfully run and insert unique documents, And also
>   produces error later after successful insertion. So You will come to
>   know that there were duplicate records But now in the database, all
>   records are unique.

Reference [InsertMany with ordered parameter](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#insertmany_insertMany)